# What are the semantics of 'reconfiguration level' for dynamic reconfigure?

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [dynamic_reconfigure tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode#preview), it is claimed that dependence on `driver_base` is specific to the tutorial, yet an enum type from `driver_base` is used to set the 'reconfiguration level'.

Is this just a field to be interpreted however we like, and just used with the `driver_base/SensorLevels` message in this case? Or is the `driver_base/SensorLevels` message *the* standard for the 'reconfiguration level' field semantics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9883/what-are-the-semantics-of-%27reconfiguration-level%27-for-dynamic-reconfigure?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whatever value you send there gets passed through to the `dynamic_reconfigure` callback as a second argument (note that the callback takes two arguments, not the usual one). Ergo, the reconfiguration level semantics are up to you.

Sticking with the `driver_base` model probably isn't a bad idea, though.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-19**:
Thanks : )

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-18**:
I've created us a ticket; see #5015.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-18**:
Correct by the standard of "what I wrote correctly describes the behavior". I agree that the wiki documentation should be improved to specify the intended semantics.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-17**:
Correct by what standard? Yes, it will compile/function, but the question is more about agreed convention to prevent confusion in the future/prevent code rot.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-17**:
Deductive, but correct.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-17**:
Is your answer authoritative, or deduced?  It seems like a really bad idea for people to be arbitrarily determining their own semantics for such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with Mac's answer.

I had this discussion with Blaise Gassend a year or so ago. He said the `level` parameter is just a bit mask. It can be used to classify sets of parameters in any way that is convenient to the package defining the server. The bits for all parameter classes that have changed will be `ORed` together for the service callback.

One useful classification scheme is suggested by the `driver_base` states:

1. Parameters that can only be changed while the device is closed.
2. Parameters that can be changed while the device is not streaming.
3. Parameters that can be changed while the device is open and streaming.

But, servers are free to classify their parameters any way they like.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4